# How can I use django.auth.views.login?

Tags: python, django, authentication

How can I use django.auth.views.login? I am trying to make a user login but I can't figure out how to use it. Is there a thing you add to urls.py. I have an intermediate understanding of django. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a quick and simple login view you just have to add the following to your urlpatterns in your urls.py file (You can change the regex to match whatever location you need it to match):

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

Next, add a directory called "registration" in your main templates folder, and within that create an html file called "login.html". This is the file that will be rendered with the login form. You can customize it to your hearts content, but here's a basic version:

```
<html>
<head> <title>User Login</title> </head>
<body>
<h1>User Login</h1>
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match!
Please try again!</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
<p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>{{ form.username }}</p>
<p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>{{ form.password }}</p>
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
<input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And that should do it. Obviously, there's a lot more you can do there but that should get you started. For more details you can go here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: What does 'action="."' mean? How does the form know that it is following the r'^login/$' url? Thank you...

Comment: That html file is served at `website.com/login`. So `action="."` is telling the form that once the user presses submit, POST (it know to do this because of the `method` attribute) the submitted data to "." which means the same location as the current one which happens to be website.com/login/

Comment: I have read you have to use action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}"

Comment: if you have read this from a trustable source then I guess it does. The method above definitely works as well. Feel free to test it at your own leisure.

Comment: For clarity, the regex url pattern you provided above goes in the main urls.py file rather than the app-level urls.py file. I'm new to Django and it took some fiddling to find that out. This distinction may help others in the future. Thanks for helping with my dilemma!